# Soft start for a drone battery pack?

Tags: power-electronics, component-selection, drone

I want to design  drone landing pad that will automatically begin charging my drone as soon as it lands, I'm planning on having the drone legs have some pogo pins that will touch the pad it lands on which will have power through it. The issue I'm contemplating is that if the landing pad has a voltage from a cccv, I'm worried it will cause a large inrush current the second it lands on the pad. I wanted to attempt a soft start circuit, I have done some research and lots of typologies use quite a bit of components, I want to make it as simple as possible. Will a simple capacitor in parallel like this work? maybe even adding a Inrush current Limiter like an NTC Thermistor in series for current? Or am I thinking of this way incorrectly?

[image]

Also, for reference, the drone battery will need about ~16 V at 23 amps, I placed an 18 V source in LTspice for some voltage drops that will be in the system like a full wave rectifier for reverse polarity  protection etc.. Last thing, I want the ramp up to be about 10 seconds till steady state

Comment: Where is the capacitor situated?

Comment: I have a 4H capacitor just before the resistor simulating the battery pack. My understanding is the capacitor size will modify the rise time of the voltage and current trends, so I just picked one that gave me a rise time of about 10 seconds with that resistance.

Comment: But where will the capacitor be in the actual circuit - on the base, or in the drone?

Comment: Gotcha. Ideally I would want it in the base, I don't want to have to mount too many additional electronics to the drone.

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid a large inrush current the second it lands on the pad?

Comment: Proper CC will limit I to no more than the CC setting - which should not be harmful.

Comment: My thought is that it will just provide an overall protection to the components and parts of the system, allowing currents to ramp up instead of take an initial hit of 23A. Am I incorrect? I just assumed it would keep things safer and last longer.

Comment: Also I guess a side thought...if I wanted to keep the landing pads at a zero voltage to prevent mishaps, how could I even go about that? Sorry pretty new to electronics and this forum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will a simple capacitor in parallel like this work?

No, it will *increase* the surge current.

You have made two mistakes in the simulation:-

1. If the the drone is not connected when the cccv charger is powered up, it will charge the capacitor to full voltage. You should put a switch in the simulation representing the connection to the drone.
2. When the drone lands and makes contact, the capacitor will discharge into it with **no** current limiting. The battery pack should be modeled as a voltage with a small resistance in series.

A better scheme would not turn the charger on until detecting that the drone is connected, eg. by monitoring the voltage on the pins, or via a microswitch or other proximity sensor. How to ramp the current up slowly when the charger is turned on depends on the circuit used, but it would probably involve a smaller capacitor in the current regulating loop.

> the drone battery will need about ~16 V at 23 amps, I placed an 18 V
>   source in LTspice for some voltage drops that will be in the system
>   like a full wave rectifier for reverse polarity protection etc.

I fear you do not understand the requirements for safe charging and operation of lithium batteries. 23 A is a lot of current, suggesting a very large battery pack and/or high charging rate. The voltage needs to be precisely limited, and some protection against charger malfunction included. Cell balance should monitored and the charger cut off if any cell goes too high. Large drones can be lethal too. 'As simple as possible' is not good if it compromises safety.

Comment: Ah yes! The alternative would be to have the capacitor mounted on the drone itself, preventing it to start in a charged state while connected to the pads. Would that even be an efficient way to limit current either way? Would a NTC Thermistor be better? I actually have a buddy I'm working with, he's doing all the battery and BMS work, I am pretty hands off on that, the specs I gave where just a quick thought that he gave me to work from, I'm sure we'll be more specific when the time comes.

Comment: I do agree that having the pad turn on once the drone lands is a better alternative to having the cccv on constantly, I'll look into that.

Comment: Forget the capacitor and NTC. Neither of them will do any good placed between the charge and battery. Soft start (if needed) should be done in the control circuit of the charger, where it doesn't have to deal with 23A.